# Unable to list text-embedding model for vector search in Azure open AI service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai

I am encountering an issue while trying to add vector search for Azure open AI service within the context of cognitive search. After selecting the tickmark, I am unable to list any models, even though there is an existing text-embedding-model available. What could be the possible reason for this discrepancy and how can I resolve it?

[image: pic from Add datasource option]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have a deployed embedding model in your Azure OpenAI service. Please verify that you have a deployed text embedding model by viewing deployed models on the **Deployments** tab. At this time, please note that only `text-embedding-ada-002` is supported.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/ai-services/openai/use-your-data-quickstart?tabs=command-line&pivots=programming-language-studio

If you don't have a model deployed, you can follow these instructions to deploy the `text-embedding-ada-002` model in your Azure OpenAI service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/create-resource?pivots=web-portal#deploy-a-model

Comment: Thanks. It works. Are there additional costs associated with deploying a model beyond the costs associated with its usage?

Comment: No, you only pay for what you use.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/openai-service/